# What is the difference between NET40-RequiresCastle and NET40 version of Moq?

Tags: .net, moq, castle

In the distribution of moq, there are two versions, NET40-RequiresCastle and NET40. The NET40-RequiresCastle seems to have much smaller size than the NET40, but requires Castle during runtime. Is the difference only the fact that Castle is embedded inside the NET40 version, or is there going to be difference in performance, usage, etc?

Is there a reason to use NET40-RequiresCastle instead of NET40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MoQ uses Castle DynamicProxy for proxy generation. In order to simplify the deploy that dll is "IL merged" into the redistributable that does not require Castle Library. If you already use the DynamicProxy library in your project you would probabli use the RequireCastle distribution, to avoid having the dll deployed twice. If you don't use Castle somewhere else in your project, you probably prefer the merged one, since you have less dll to take care in the deploy.

Comment: so there's no side effect of using the merged one other than possible the increase in size? We are using Castle.Windsor (not sure if this contains the Castle DynamicProxy) and the version is mismatched with one used by moq

Comment: @LouisRhys did you try with the merged one? does it solve the problem ?

Comment: It did.. which is why I asked whether there's any downside to using the merged one...

Comment: @LouisRhys stay with the merged one, the other solution could be GACing both castle DynamicProxy versions, but I would strongly avoid it.

Comment: @LouisRhys  in order to me, no downside