# Moq Release 4: What's the difference between NET35 and NET40

Tags: unit-testing, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, moq

I am new to Moq and want to use the [latest Release](http://moq.googlecode.com/files/Moq.4.0.10827.Final.zip). In the download there are 3 variants, one for .NET 3.5 and two for .NET 4. What is the difference between the .NET versions? **Does the 3.5 version miss any features compared to 4?**

Note: The difference between the two version for .NET 4 are already [covered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12104769/79485) and not asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.5 version has references to 3.5 .Net Framework libraries (mscorlib, System, SystemConfiguration, System.Core, System.Web, System.Xml).

Version 4 references same assemblies, but from .Net Framework 4. So, if target framework of your project is 4, you should use this Moq version.